# Return distinct values in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to solve an issue where I have to get distinct result in the search.

```
{
        "name" : "ABC",
        "favorite_cars" : [ "ferrari","toyota" ]
      }, {
        "name" : "ABC",
        "favorite_cars" : [ "ferrari","toyota" ]
      }, {
        "name" : "GEORGE",
        "favorite_cars" : [ "honda","Hyundae" ]
      }
```

When I perform a term query on favourite cars "**ferrari**". I get two results whose name is **ABC**. I simply want that the result returned should be one in this case. So my requirement will be if I can apply a distinct on name field to receive one 1 result.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know , you can't do this. The most you can do is to count them using terms aggregation. In my case , what I do is to remove them after using a Java set.  If you find a way , let me know.

Comment: @Yeikel the solution provided by Val works for me. Is it helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want is to use a `terms` aggregation on the `name` field and then a [`top_hits` sub-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) with size 1, like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "favorite_cars": "ferrari"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "names": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "single_result": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That way, you'll get a single term `ABC` and then nested into it a single matching document

Comment: Thanks @Val that really helped.

Comment: @Val Do you know how "expensive" this aggregations are?

Comment: This one is not expensive at all.